# Make an executable Guile program with auto-tools?

Tags: scheme, gnu, autotools, guile, fhs

Recently started learning to use auto-tools and have been trying make a simple Guile program with it. [Following this tutorial](https://erikedrosa.com/2017/10/29/guile-projects-with-autotools.html) I got the program successfully compiling, with the .go file placed in `%site-ccache-dir` and the .scm file placed in `%site-dir`. But, the tutorial is aimed at making modules rather than a making an executable. Would just creating a link to the .scm file in `%site-dir` and placing it in `/usr/bin` be enough? What is best way of doing that with auto-tools? Below is what I currently have setup...

**guile.am:**

```
moddir=$(datadir)/guile/site/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)
godir=$(libdir)/guile/$(GUILE_EFFECTIVE_VERSION)/site-ccache

GOBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.scm=%.go)

nobase_dist_mod_DATA = $(SOURCES) $(NOCOMP_SOURCES)
nobase_go_DATA = $(GOBJECTS)

# Make sure source files are installed first, so that the mtime of
# installed compiled files is greater than that of installed source
# files.  See
# <http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-devel/2010-07/msg00125.html>
# for details.
guile_install_go_files = install-nobase_goDATA
$(guile_install_go_files): install-nobase_dist_modDATA

CLEANFILES = $(GOBJECTS)
GUILE_WARNINGS = -Wunbound-variable -Warity-mismatch -Wformat
SUFFIXES = .scm .go
.scm.go:
    $(AM_V_GEN)$(top_builddir)/pre-inst-env $(GUILD) compile $(GUILE_WARNINGS) -o "$@" "$<"
```

**bootstrap:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

autoreconf --verbose --install --force
```

**Makefile.am:**

```
include guile.am

SOURCES =               \
  example-program.scm

EXTRA_DIST =            \
  bootstrap             \
  pre-inst-env.in
```

**configure.ac:**

```
AC_INIT([example-program], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([example-program.scm])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])

GUILE_PKG([2.2])
GUILE_PROGS
if test "x$GUILD" = "x"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR(['guild' binary not found; please check your guile-2.x installation.])
fi

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([pre-inst-env], [chmod +x pre-inst-env])

AC_OUTPUT
```

**pre-inst-env.in:**

```
#!/bin/sh

abs_top_srcdir="`cd "@abs_top_srcdir@" > /dev/null; pwd`"
abs_top_builddir="`cd "@abs_top_builddir@" > /dev/null; pwd`"

GUILE_LOAD_COMPILED_PATH="$abs_top_builddir${GUILE_LOAD_COMPILED_PATH:+:}$GUILE_LOAD_COMPILED_PATH"
GUILE_LOAD_PATH="$abs_top_builddir:$abs_top_srcdir${GUILE_LOAD_PATH:+:}:$GUILE_LOAD_PATH"
export GUILE_LOAD_COMPILED_PATH GUILE_LOAD_PATH

PATH="$abs_top_builddir:$PATH"
export PATH

exec "$@"
```

**example-program.scm:**

```
#!/usr/bin/guile \
-e main -s
!#

;;; Functions.
(define count-to-100
  (lambda ()
    (define my-num 1)
    (while (<= my-num 100)
       (display my-num)
       (newline)
       (set! my-num (+ my-num 1)))))

;;; Main.
(define (main args)
  (count-to-100))
```

Comment: I'm uncertain about the Guile-specific details, but the way to produce an executable with the Autotools starts with naming the target in a `*_PROGRAMS` variable in your `Makefile.am`.  For example, `bin_PROGRAMS = example'.  You then name that target's corresponding source file in a matching `*_SOURCES` variable.  I'm don't know how much of all that other stuff you need, if any.  With the Autotools, you don't usually need to specify details for building intermediate files.

Comment: Ouch, that needed a more careful eye.  Correction: you name *all* of the target's source file***s*** in a corresponding `*_SOURCES` variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I added `bin_PROGRAMS = example` and changed `SOURCES` to `example_SOURCES`. I ran `autoreconf --verbose --install --force`, `./configure`, then finally `make` which resulted in an error complaining over a lack of input files.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what else to tell you, for as I already said, I'm unfamiliar with the Guile-specific details and can speak only to general Autotools principles.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question but still open so if it can benefit to someone...

To take advantage of the autotools features for your Guile projects, you can use [Hall](https://gitlab.com/a-sassmannshausen/guile-hall). It takes care of a lot of stuff for you to end up with the ability to call things like `make`, `make check`, `make distcheck`, `make clean`, etc...

You can find a demo [here](https://write.as/jeko/hall-a-project-manager-for-the-guile-programming-language)

Hope someone will find this information helpful...

Cheers !

Comment: Please post content here instead of links elsewhere, which may go stale.